# Use reflection to invoke a method of a class' property

Tags: c#

Assuming you have a class, say, `MainClass`. Assuming this class has a property, `MainProperty`, whose type is also another custom class, `AlternateClass`. Given as...

```
public class MainClass
{
    ...
    public AlternateClass MainProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class AlternateClass
{
    ...
    public int someAction()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to know how to invoke the `someAction`() method for `MainProperty` using reflection, the alternative of which is:

```
 MainClass instanceOfMainClass = new MainClass();
 instanceOfMainClass.MainProperty.someAction();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far concerning reflection? This seems like a very basic scenario which should be easily covered by resources on the web.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the type and an instance of each layer. Reflection gets properties and methods from the type system but performs work on instances.

Not Test, probably has a few errors in it.

```
//First Get the type of the main class.
Type typeOfMainClass = instanceOfMainClass.GetType();

//Get the property information from the type using reflection.
PropertyInfo propertyOfMainClass = typeOfMainClass.GetProperty("MainProperty");

//Get the value of the property by combining the property info with the main instance.
object instanceOfProperty = propertyOfMainClass.GetValue(instanceOfMainClass);

//Rinse and repeat.
Type typeofMainProperty = intanceOfProperty.GetType();
MethodInfo methodOfMainProperty = typeofMainProperty.GetMethod("someAction");
methodOfMainProperty.Invoke(instanceOfMainProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make use of the GetMethod() and GetProperty() Reflection methods.  You will call the respective method on the type, and then use the returned MethodInfo or PropertyInfo object against the original object.

For example:

```
MainClass theMain = new MainClass();

PropertyInfo mainProp = typeof(MainClass).GetProperty("MainProperty");

AlternateClass yourAlternate = mainProp.GetValue(mainClass);

MethodInfo someActionMethod = typeof(AlternateClass).GetMethod("someAction");

someActionMethod.Invoke(yourAlternate);
```